# blender 2.8 - objects are scaling weirdly

Tags: scale

when i try to scale my objects on blender, they scale weirdly. the reason may have been because i applied rotation & scale to it (shift+a), but i'm not sure. i've tried redoing whatever i did wrong (changing pivot point and origin), but nothing seemed to do the trick.

before, i was able to scale the object on the video below as if it was one object (didn't scale weirdly)

i hope i was able to express myself correctly. thank you!

**video of what's happening**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIh6D.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have enabled the *Only Origins* option, which allows to move the objects apart from each others.

[image]